# Magento cart quantity not available

Tags: magento

I have such observer

```
<events>
 <sales_quote_add_item>
         <observers>
            <reservation_observer_order_save_before1>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Mageec_Total_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>updatePrice</method>
            </reservation_observer_order_save_before1>
         </observers>
 </sales_quote_add_item>
</events>
```

And function updatePrice go below:

```
public function updatePrice($observer){

    $event = $observer->getEvent();

    $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();


    if ($quote_item->getProductType() == "virtual"){
        $new_price = (float)$quote_item->getProduct()->getPrice();
        $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);

        $qty = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getSummaryQty(); //return 0
                    $qty = $quote_item->getQty(); //return 0 too
        Mage::log(print_r($qty,true));



        $quote_item->setTotalPrice( $new_price * $qty );
    }
}
```

I can't get cart quantity or at least quoteitem qty. I think It's because of this observer executes before cart object is filled. So where can I get qty in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution myself.
When we place first product to cart, run sales_quote_add_item observer. But It's FIRST product and cart has not been saved yet. Thefore code where I get cart quanty return 0. Thefore solution is saving cart before working with order. Code example goes below:

```
public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer  $observer){
        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        $cart->save();


        $quote_item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    if ($quote_item->getProductType() == "virtual"){
            $new_price = (float)$quote_item->getProduct()->getPrice();
        $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);

        $totalItemsInCart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount(); //Total items in cart
        Mage::log( "Total Product in Cart : " );  
        Mage::log( print_r($totalItemsInCart, true) );  

        $qty = 1;

        if($totalItemsInCart)   
        {               
            Mage::log( "Total Product in Cart : ".$totalItemsInCart );          
            $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getData();
            Mage::log( "Total Quantity In Cart    : ".(int)$cart['items_qty'] ); 
            $qty = (int)$cart['items_qty'];
        }






        $quote_item->setTotalPrice( $new_price * $qty );
        $quote_item->save();
    }

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see lines:

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->save();
```

These ones is solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing. This issue was haunting us from months.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code ,If does not work let me inform

```
$totalItemsInCart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount(); //Total items in cart

if($totalItemsInCart)   
{               
    echo "Total Product in Cart : ".$totalItemsInCart;          
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getData();
    echo "Total Quantity In Cart    : ".(int)$cart['items_qty'];    
}
```

Comment: if block never run, $totalItemsInCart is empty

Comment: @Portnyagin Mikhail Have you added some product to your cart? try to print_r($totalItemsInCart) and see the collection.

Comment: yes, I have added.  print_r($totalItemsInCart)  returns 0. And I can see product in the cart